# Automate simple login with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, automation

I am trying to automate simple login with python selenium, but I am confused what element to catch, because "class" is dynamic

HTML/Java code

[image]

Here the code added:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://qachassis.tangocode.com/login")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-dxgOiQ bkWMot").send_keys("Login")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("sc-dxgOiQ bkWMot").send_keys("Password")
driver.find_element_by_name("login-submit-button").click()
```

Comment: Share the HTML and we can advise you.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can try this,

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://qachassis.tangocode.com/login")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-testid='login-user-name-input']").send_keys("Login")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-testid='login-password-input']").send_keys("Password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-testid='login-submit-button']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now it inputs credentials and stops. It does not click "Login" button.

Answer (score 0):

sorry there is a mistake in the previous code, please refer below code

```
enter code here

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\WebDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://qachassis.tangocode.com/login")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-testid='login-user-name-input']").send_keys("Login")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@data-testid='login-password-input']").send_keys("Password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-testid='login-submit-button']").click()
```